# SQL Server PowerShell cannot find path error

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I cannot use `Set-Location` to change to a database. I have loaded the SQL Server snapins. I can use `Set-Location` to get to `SQL\Localhost\SQLEXPRESS\`, and I can show the paths under the server node with `Get-ChildItem`. However, if I try to change to a known database on my machine, the `Set-Location` call fails.

[image: Powershell path not found]

Am I missing a library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the answer on MSDN Social [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d1059c82-9c1c-4f7d-9cea-38102436165b/). It's not enough to simply load the PowerShell plugins. You have a few more commands that also need to be run. ([Solution source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281962.aspx).)

```
Push-Location
cd $sqlpsPath
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
Update-TypeData -PrependPath SQLProvider.Types.ps1xml 
update-FormatData -prependpath SQLProvider.Format.ps1xml 
Pop-Location
```